# PHP Set Now to format YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: php

I need to set a variable to the current date in this format: eg: 2012-05-12 , I get that's YYYY-MM-DD ?

I've tried:

```
$date = date("yyyy-mm-dd", strtotime(now));
```

but this is not saving the date to mysql so it's coming out as 0000-00-00.

The field is set as type: date in the mysql db.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `yyyy-mm-dd` will give you `12121212-1111-1313`, use, as @MartinBean explained `$date = date('Y-m-d');`

Comment: Remember that 'NOW' in MySQL is a function so it needs to be called as `NOW()`. While the equivalent to it in PHP is the 'time' function called as `time()`. In your code `strtotime(now)` probably should be replaced either with `time()` or with `strtotime($variable_name_containing_string_date)`.

Comment: @MihaiStancu He’s not using “now” in a MySQL context above though, but incorrectly as a string for PHP’s `strtotime()` function.

Comment: @MartinBean I forgot strtotime has that. Then it should work provided he uses quotes around `'NOW'`. But it's superfluous because `date('Y-m-d', strtotime('NOW')) === date('Y-m-d', time()) === date('Y-m-d')`.

Comment: @MihaiStancu I know, as per my answer.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Easy:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');
```

see
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 14):

Always check the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), and you’ll find the format you’ll need is:

```
<?php date('Y-m-d'); ?>
```

**EDIT:** Also, you don’t need to specify the time as the second parameter, as `date()` will use now by default. It should be noted that your syntax there is wrong too though, as it would be `strtotime('now')`, as “now“ is a string it needs to be quoted.

Answer (score 7):

use

```
$date = date("Y-m-d");
```

Then save the `$date` variable to the database