# Incorrect date value: '' for column 'date' at row 1 in the Server

Tags: php, ubuntu, innodb

My PHP Code worked with the date all the time with XAMPP and PHPmyadmin. Now i wanted to put everything (the database and my files) to my Server and it looks like that everything works except my date..
I tried multiple code, but i didn't found the right one yet, what am i missing?

here is everything related to 'date':

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $date = (isset($_POST['datum']) && !empty($_POST['datum'])) ? $_POST['datum'] : null;
    $date = strtotime($date);
    $date = date('d-m-Y', $date);
}
$currentDate = date('Y-m-d');


<input type="date" class="inputright" id="inputright" placeholder="Datum *" name="datum" required="required" value="<?php echo $currentDate;?>">

$query  = " INSERT INTO bestellung (nr, datum, bestellid, wert, por, ebest, gebucht, geliefert, track, kunde_id)";
$query .=      "VALUES ('$nr', '$date', '$bestellid', '$wert', '$por','$ebest', 'No','No', 'No', '$kunde_id' )";
```

and the comloumn date from my table:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crxkY.png)

appreciate any help

Comment: Check your server DB date format.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23616461/7750416
check this

Comment: Where is your insert/update string?

Comment: @Kashif the quotes didn't solved the error ..

Comment: You're inserting an empty string into the date column. You'll need to go through and find out why. Are you running the query when you shouldn't be? Is `$date` correct? Echo out your `$query` to see what it contains.

Comment: i updated the question with my query

Comment: Your date column is really `'d-m-Y'` format?  Probably not. and that's not good.

Answer (score -1):

When your `datum` column is of type [date](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-type-syntax.html), you should format it to get it in this format `'YYYY-MM-DD'`.

So in stead of `'d-m-Y'` use `'Y-m-d'`

See also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13361356/3710053)